# Using the result of a query to determine a value in a where clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, variables

So basically I've got a query where I want to filter using a date, however that date may change depending on what datas in the system.

If there's no records with a date of >='X', I want to use >='Y' instead

Currently I've got something like the following mess (Pseudocoded down to avoid using actual table names and such)

```
    With a as (SELECT 
count(column_id) as num
 FROM tableA
    WHERE ADate >= getdate() - 8)
,
b as (SELECT
case when num = '0' then getdate() - 15 else getdate() - 8 end as DateToUseInQuery
from A)

SELECT * 
FROM tableB

Bunch of joins to other tables

WHERE BDate >= DateToUseInQuery
```

The general idea being is if there's no records for the week beforehand, use 2 weeks beforehand

I tried using a query within the where clause like:

```
WHERE BDate >= (SELECT DateToUseInQuery FROM b)
```

But the query ran for 11 minutes before I stopped it (Up from about 18 seconds before I tried to put this extra bit in)

I've been thinking about trying to set a variable as the date, but I can't do it in a CTE, and when I do it after, it breaks everything else.

So basically:

Is there an easier way to do this than the cack-handed way I'm trying?

If my way is fine, how can I pass that date properly into the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. I am using a nested select and case statement to determine the number of days.

There may be a prettier way, but this works.

```
SELECT COUNT(column_id) AS num FROM TableA
WHERE ADate >=
DATEADD(Day,
    (SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM TableA
        WHERE ADate >= DATEADD(Day,-8,GETDATE())) 
    THEN  -8
    ELSE  -15
    END AS 'dt')
,GETDATE());
```

Comment: Absolute hero mate, that's done the trick. Ended up having to shift some stuff around, but  was exactly thew thing.

"There may be a prettier way, but this works"

Haha, ai, that's exactly what I was thinking when I was on this. Though considering my problem is because of poorly structured data, I guess the solution was never gonna be elegant.